# Iterating through nested dictionary is not working in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to print results from nested dictionary

```
var variations_hash = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
```

But it throws some random error

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var variations_hash = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
        var variations = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        variations["available"] = new List<string> { "hi" };
        var stores = new[] { "s", "m", "xl", "xxl", "xxxl", "v" };
        string color_trans = "blue";
        foreach (var sto in stores)
        {
            variations_hash[sto] = variations;
        }

        foreach(var job in variations_hash.Key())
        {
            foreach (var innerDict in variations_hash[key].Select(k => k.Value))
            {
                Console.Write(innerDict);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Error:

> Error  CS1061  'Dictionary>>' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   ConsoleApplication1 c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 29
>
> Error  CS0103  The name 'key' does not exist in the current context  ConsoleApplication1   c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 31
>
> Warning    CS0219  The variable 'color_trans' is assigned but its value is never used
>   ConsoleApplication1 c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 20

How to loop and print all the contents of nested dictionary?

Comment: Use `.Keys` instead of `variations_hash.Key()`

Comment: How do you want to print it at all? What is the expected output, should it also contain the keys?

Comment: Those aren't "random errors" at all. Those error messages are very specific and seem pretty clear to me. What do you not understand about them, what did you expect the `Key()` method to do? Which variable did you expect to refer to in `variations_hash[key]`?

Comment: Lol @JonSkeet. You've got the superpower of understanding random things, maybe we should be friends ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you could correct the issue by replacing `Key()` with `Keys` proprty, this would not be the optimal way of iterating a dictionary, because you would have to retrieve the object for each key in the loop.

It is more efficient to iterate key-value pairs, like this:

```
foreach(var vHash in variations_hash) {
    Console.WriteLine("variations_hash key = {0}", vHash.Key);
    foreach (var inner in vHash.Value) {
        // Print inner dictionary key followed by comma-separated list
        Console.WriteLine(
            "--- {0}: {1}"
        ,   inner.Key
        ,   string.Join(", ", inner.Value)
        );
    }
}
```

Note how each loop gives you access to not only the key of the dictionary being iterated (i.e. `vHash.Key` and `inner.Key`) but also to the value associated with that key.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `variations_hash.Keys`

Also nested dictionary value is a `List`, so use `SelectMany` to flatten the structure.

```
foreach(var job in variations_hash.Keys)
{
    foreach (var innerDict in variations_hash[key].SelectMany(k => k.Value))
    {
        Console.Write(innerDict);
    }
}
```

Above code might fix your compilation issues and prints all nested dictionary values, but to print the nested dictionary in proper format you could use below code.

```
foreach(var kv in variations_hash)
{
    foreach (var nestedKv in kv.Values)
    {
        Console.Write("Key {0}- Values{1}", nestedKv.Key, string.Join(",", nestedKv.Value));
    }
}
```

and same thing using `Linq`

```
var lines = variations_hash.SelectMany(x=>x.Values)
                           .ToList().
                           .ForEach(kv => Console.WriteLine("Key {0}- Values{1}", kv.Key, string.Join(",", kv.Value)));
```

Comment: Shouldn't the loop variable be `key` instead of `job`?

Comment: Ideally yes, since OP used job variable I thought it has some meaning :-)  @YacoubMassad